# Magmi changes attribute options order after 2200 SKUs

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, frontend, magmi

My current version of Magento is 1.9.2.1. I'm using "[Easylife Switcher](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher)" to make the first option of each attribute selected automatically. I'm also using the "[Product attribute order fix](https://github.com/robbieaverill/magento-attribute-option-order-fix)" to have all options ordered correctly according to my default settings.

When I import products with Magmi (v0.7.22_git) everything works fine (apparently) until the 10th configurable product. Each configurable product have 220 Simple Products.

This is how the options box looks like up to the 10th configurable product:

[image]

Everything is as it should be!

After the 10th configurable product:

[image]

After the 10th all the products have the same error.
If i disable the "[Product attribute order fix](https://github.com/robbieaverill/magento-attribute-option-order-fix)" I can see that the options being automatically selected are the first of each attribute without my default order.

Live examples:

Good: http://www.teelegend.com/catalog/product/view/id/2200

Bad: http://www.teelegend.com/catalog/product/view/id/2860

Can somebody help me? I'm really having a hard time trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Those plugins typically use javascript to select a particular configuration.  On the page you link as "good", I get a jQuery is not defined error.  I assume this is not related as it's on the "good" page.  However, on the "Bad" page, I also get these three javascript errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
```

So, seeing how these errors only show on the "bad" page, I'd say it's a good clue.

If you click around on the vertical 'icon bar', you'll see these errors output again in the browser.   It appears as though it's trying to select a tab on this icon bar, errors and cannot continue.